# Associated Content & SEO, Sitemaps with External links, using CNAMEs to include External Links as my own in the sitemap

Tags: seo, sitemap, cname

Is there any HTML code or page paramater or metaname that can tell search engines that the content of a page is closely linked to another page on another domain.. 
I keep the content metatag updated and also the keyword metatag. 
I don't want to show these links to my visitors.

1)
I need to know if there is a protocol for communicating related links specifically to crawlers so as to improve my ranking

Is there any way via code I can tell crawlers (crawlers specifically, like how No Follow is addressed to crawlers) that `mydomain.com/Porduct.php` is closely linked to say

```
 http://ebay.com/sameProduct  
 http://wikipedia.com/GenericProduct or
 http://google.com?q=someKeywords
```

Should I include external links or `CNAME mapped External links(Read Q3)` inside the content tag ?? Would that make a difference

2)
Can I include these links in my Sitemap.. Common sense would suggest that links in my sitemap should be hoisted on my domain. Still though I did ask since the sitemap takes in the full URL including the domain name.

3)
If a particular well indexed page has content largely similar to mine can I map a CNAME of my page to that site and include that in the sitemap?? would that amount to cheating ??

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'm not sure what do you want to achieve there. Search engines in general are already pretty good at recognizing what your page is about. If your content is about product A, write a description about product A, have images about product A, let your users comment about or review product A, or add microdata to your page (i.e. http://schema.org/Product). All these will help search engines recognize that your page is about that product, just like that page on the other site which also have content about the same product.

To answer your questions:

1) I'm not aware of any tag like that which would also be supported by search engines.

2) In your Sitemap you can include only URLs that point to a location on the same hostname the Sitemap is hosted on (there are some exceptions, but those are irrelevant now). See http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html for more info about Sitemaps.

3) A CNAME resource record specifies that the *domain name* is an alias of another domain name, and thus it can't be used the way you described.

Lastly, you're trying to do something for crawlers which is usually a bad idea. Create an awesome website, something useful for the users, something they would love and they'd miss in case you closed the shop. Just focus on the user and all else will come.